# forecast() function doesn't work with ETS- or STL-model

Tags: r, forecast

I am trying to use the forecast() function in R on different ETS- or STL-objects. I get the same error message everytime.

For example, if I try to run the code from RDocumentation.org about the forecast() function (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.13/topics/forecast)

```
fit <- ets(window(WWWusage, end=60))
fc <- forecast(WWWusage, model=fit)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in forecast(fit_ets) : 
  'object' should be 'Arima' or 'estimate' class estimated 
         from arima() or estimate()
```

I am using RStudio and have updated to version 4.0.4.

Any ideas are much appreaciated! Thanks :-)